# Java Server Pages, Java iOS and Codename One

Tags: java, ios, eclipse, xcode

Let it be known that I am an ASP.NET C# developer.

A client of mine has brought me a Java iOS app, checkout the file structure and files:

[image]

The `webapps` folder contains:

[image]

And the `iOS` folder contains an Xcode project:

[image]

**There is an iOS app that you can download from iTunes and the client says this is the code.**

So I am thinking this code is developed in Eclipse or Netbeans and the Xcode project, on a Mac, takes those Java Server Pages and wraps up in a shim or app wrapper for download in iTunes. Its not a native application, basically the iOS app is a container for a JavaServer Pages website.

**If am correct so far, since I am on a Windows, I want to use Codename One to continue development of this app. Codename One has a plugin for Eclipse. Can Codename One compile/work with Java Server Pages?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how Codename One works.

JSP code will run on the server unrelated to Codename One, the xcode project won't work with Codename One. You will need to write the mobile code from scratch.